# Replace JQuery show() with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to replace JQuery with pure javascript. And trying to open a bootstrap 4 modal.

Now I have the following line:

```
$("#signup-box").show(); //Jquery
```

And I try to replace it with:

```
document.getElementById("signup-box").style.display = "block";
```

But this is not working.

Also tried the following line

```
document.getElementById("signup-box").style.visibility = "visible";
```

So far no success...

Comment: But, first of all, why do you wanna do this?

Comment: Have you also tried changing the opacity?

Comment: Does `document.getElementById("signup-box")` work? Are you running this code at the bottom of the DOM?

Comment: Try to learn pure javascript ;)

Comment: You're refering to the Bootstrap modal. Its `.show()` method is not a pure JQuery `show` that modifies only the CSS.

Comment: That's a very good point.  https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/js/dist/modal.js

Comment: If the `#signup-box` has a class like `hide` you could remove that class with `var hide = document.getElementsByClassName("hide");
hide.parentNode.removeChild(hide);`.

Comment: @PatMellon woah, that's not removing a class.  That's removing an element.  Also `hide` there would be a NodeList or whatever list object `getElementsByClassName` returns

Answer (score 0):

Hide or show an element using jQuery:

```
$(".blog-post").hide();
$(".blog-post").show();
```

Hide or show an element using vanilla JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector(".blog-post").style.display = "none";//hide
document.querySelector(".blog-post").style.display = "block"; //show
```